# I need to find a Mobius transformation that maps unit circle to itself and $0$ to$1/2.$

Tags: complex-analysis

Earlier in the exercise we saw that transformations of the form

f$_{a}$(z) = $\frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z}$ take unit-disk into unit disk.I just plugged $z=0$ to see that $a=-0.5$ works.

Now my question is, does it take unit circle to unit circle?

Comment: Since Möbius transformations are automorphisms of the sphere, it follows that $f_a(\partial U) = \partial f_a(U)$ for every $U \subset \mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $f_a(z)=\frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z}$ maps the unit circle to the unit circle.
Now just choose $a=-\frac{1}{2}$ ... So the transformation $\color{red}{\frac{2z+1}{z+2}}$

If $z=\cos \theta +i\sin \theta $ then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{2z+1}{z+2} &=& \frac{2\cos \theta+1 +2i\sin \theta}{\cos \theta+2 +i\sin \theta} \\
&=& \frac{2\cos \theta+1 +2i\sin \theta}{\cos \theta+2 +i\sin \theta} \times \frac{\cos \theta+2 -i\sin \theta }{\cos \theta+2 -i\sin \theta} \\
&=& \frac{2+5\cos \theta +2 \cos^{2} \theta +2 \sin^2 \theta+i \sin \theta(4+2 cos \theta-1-2 \cos \theta)}{ (2+\cos \theta)^2+\sin^2 \theta}\\
&=& \frac{4+5\cos \theta +3i \sin \theta}{ 5+4\cos \theta}
\end{eqnarray*}
it is quite easy to see that this has unit modulus.

Comment: Having magnitude $1$ does not guarantee that it maps to the unit circle.

Comment: Good point ... How do I show the map is onto ?... Give me a few moments to remedy ? @MarkViola

Comment: No worry; take your time.